# HTML Drop Down Menu - Default Value

Tags: html

I'm making a dropdown menu in HTML and was trying to figure out how to pre-select a drop down value when the page loads. I've tried the following, using the `selected` option to indicate what value I want to be the default upon load. Though, this doesn't seem to work and I still end up with the first option being the default. I'm sure it's really simple but is there

```
<select selected="3">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Rather than manually put it in the `<option value>` tag, since these options are being generated via a loop, is there a way in the `<select>` tag to indicate what option should be defaulted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selected` property of the `<option>` you want selected by default:

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

You can set that property programatically, if you update your question to include how you are generating, I can update this to show you how.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having it in the `<option>` tag like I mention at the end of my post?

Comment: I haven't written the code yet just playing around with some stuff, but is there a way to indicate in the `<select>` tag perhaps?